# Setting rounded rectangle minmum height affects width

Tags: tikz-pgf, width, height, bugs

I'm having troubles trying to modify a rounded rectangle minimum height without affecting the node width. I know there are some stretches boolean for trapezium or triangle to make it but I didn't find anything similar for rounded rectangles.

Below is a simple code highlighting the problem :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle right arc = concave,  rounded rectangle left arc = concave,
rounded rectangle arc length=100, minimum height=2cm](text1){texte};
\node [draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle right arc = concave,  rounded rectangle left arc = concave,
rounded rectangle arc length=100, right = of text1]{texte};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Results]

Comment: There is something weird about the source code. It computes the node width but never uses it.

Comment: I filed a bug report. Stay tuned. https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/834